# How to get count of a certain record with a specific value in MarkLogic xquery

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I am trying to get count of a record for a given condition.

Count the number of Ancillary Price in all documents in a collection where the Ancillary Price is greater than 1000.

I am trying the below XQuery for that, it gives me this below response:

> Returned sequence of 532 items in 9007.0781 ms. (-361.0691 ms. compared to previous run)

And along with it prints value of 1 in each row for all 532 rows.

However my expected result is to get the count as result: 532 in my result page.

Can you please help to identify the XQuery issue here?

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
for $x in collection("GTM2_Shipment")
where ($x/*:Shipment/*:Ancillary/*:QuotePrice/text() > 1000) 
return (count($x))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure is slightly incorrect.

Ref: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xquery_flwor.asp

*Try:*

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
fn:count(
   for $x in collection("GTM2_Shipment")
   where ($x/*:Shipment/*:Ancillary/*:QuotePrice/text() > 1000) 
   return $x
)
```

*Or simply:*

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
fn:count(collection("GTM2_Shipment")[./*:Shipment/*:Ancillary/*:QuotePrice/text() > 1000])
```

However, eventually these will not scale.
Model your data where each shipment is in it's own document and then you can use an estimate such as:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
xdmp:estimate(cts:search(fn:count(collection("GTM2_Shipment"), {a range query to your quotePrice }))
```

Comment: Thanks David it works as expected. 
Can we make a make a Template using this xquery . As I want to put this in a template with different conditions like this above one and put the count names as column names and the values in the column value.

Comment: NO Problem.  I will not clutter the answer above with turning the above into what you want because it answers a specific question and keeps StackOverflow clean and useful.   However, this should get you started:  https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/import_modules  understand the difference between a  main module and function module. You want a function module for what you describe